# why does client need the size of the server to connect to it in c

Tags: c, sockets, networking, server

well in python you just give the IP and the port like connect(( "0.0.0.0" , 123 ))  .

but in c its like this :

```
connect(s ,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server) )
```

why does the program need the server size to connect to the server?

Comment: C is a lower-level language than Python, it trades away some ease-of-programming in favor of better runtime efficiency.  Therefore, many things that are easy in Python are not-quite-so-easy in C.

Answer (score 3):

The `connect` call can take several different types of socket address structures, such as `sockaddr_in`, `sockaddr_in6`, `sockaddr_un`, etc.

The size is passed in so that the function knows how big the input structure actually is.